# Haskell Conflicting family instance declarations

Tags: haskell

I try to define a division function for two Int types

```
class Dnum a b where
    type DivType a b
    _div::a->b-> DivType a b

instance Dnum Int Integer where
    type DivType Int Integer = Integer
    _div a b = div (fromIntegral a)  b 

instance Dnum Int Int where
    type DivType Int Int = Integer
    _div x y = div (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral y)

instance (Num a) => Dnum a a where
    type DivType a a = a 
    _div x y = div x y
```

Here is my main:

```
main = do 
        let n = 3::Int
        print $ _div n n
```

Got Error:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
      DivType Int Int = Integer -- Defined at MyLib.hs:67:10
      DivType a a = a -- Defined at MyLib.hs:71:10
   |
67 |     type DivType Int Int = Integer
```

It seems to me the function
`_div Int Int` has some issue, I'm not sure why it said "conflicting family instance",
but `_div Int Integer` has no issue at all.

Anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: The code you posted alone doesn't produce this error. More specifically, if `type DivType Int Int = Integer` is really on line 67, what's the context for `DivType a a = a` on line 71? My guess is that you have a more generic instance of `Dnum` that `Int`/`Int` also matches, and the compiler can't figure out which one to use.

Comment: Sorry, I just add my main

Comment: That's still not enough to reproduce your problem; what you have here runs fine and outputs 1.

Comment: Sorry, I miss the instance for the code, now it should product the error

Comment: I forget the technical reasons for this, but the compiler simply can't (or doesn't) try to figure out that `Dnum Int Int` is more specific than `Num a => Dnum a a` and should be preferred.

Comment: I hesitate to provide an answer, because the best I can do is suggest removing the generic instance to avoid the conflict. (By the way, `Dnum Int Integer` doesn't cause a problem because `Int` and `Integer`, being two separate types, doesn't also match `Dnum a a`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that instances the type family instances on lines 67 and 71 overlap, since on line 67 you assert that `DivType Int Int = Integer`, but on line 71 you say that for any `Num a`, `DivType a a = a`, which means in particular that `DivType Int Int = Int`, so it's unclear how to resolve `DivType Int Int`.

In contrast, `DivType Int Integer` does not overlap with anything, since `DivType a a` requires the two types to match.